# execution of a sh script generate others file

Tags: bash, debian, sh

I have an easy script sh with this trivial content:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

echo "Example sh"
```

When I execute the script with ./sample.sh I see correctly the echo value, but in the same folder script I see others file without extension named as d2utmpJvd8r6 for example, with the same content of sample.sh. How can avoid this situation?

thanks

Comment: Can it be some temporary file generated by your text editor?

Comment: if you remove the temporary file, does a new temporary file re-appear when you just run `./sample.sh`?

Comment: This is not coming from the shell, it's from something else.

Comment: If you use `ls -i sample.sh d2utmpJvd8r6` do they have thd same inode number?

Comment: Did you generate that file using `dos2unix`?  That file looks like a temp file from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved. The file was opening by another process, and when I try to manipulate it via the command dos2unix the system create a tmp file.